# Using Firebase realtime database indexes

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My query:

```
    const query = ref.child(`/text_preview_user/${user_id}`).orderByChild('last_timestamp').limitToFirst(150);

    query
        .once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {

            console.log(snapshot);

            const orderedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                let arr = [];
                snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

                    console.log(childSnapshot);
                    arr.push(childSnapshot.val());

                });
                resolve(arr);
            });

            orderedPromise.then((valueArr) => {

                console.log(valueArr);

            });
```

My DB:

[image]

My Index:

[image]

I am using React native and I am not getting any errors regarding the misuse of .indexOn. However when I run the simulator it doesn't show that the index is being hit. I read in the Realtime DB docs that "A node's key is indexed automatically, so there is no need to index it explicitly." But I wasn't sure exactly what that meant.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the query](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My apologies for being so delayed on providing more information. I've added my query above. Everything works perfectly, I am just unsure if my index is actually being used. As I said, I dont get any firebase errors suggesting to use a .indexOn and I read that a nodes keys are auto indexed but I am not sure what exactly that meant. Any insight from you would be super helpful. Just want to make sure this will scale

Comment: The code and index look fine. What's the problem you have when you run this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There isnt a problem that I am aware of. it works perfect. I just did not know how to verify that my indexes were being used or written correctly. this code isnt in prod yet and I have a very small data set. I wanted to make sure it could scale before launching it

Comment: You can check the logging output of your app. If it's not able to find an index, you will get a quite explicit warning there.

Comment: Im using React native so I would assume any errors would be logged in the chrome console. Problem is I wasn't getting any errors before I put the index rules in which is what has confused me on whether or not my indexes actually get used

Comment: There are ways to access the logging output on React Native too: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#accessing-console-logs But as far as I can see, the set up of your index is correct.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for taking time out of your Saturday to help me out. I love using Firebase but I don't know where I'd be without all your help on this post and every other firebase post!! @FrankvanPuffelen